# Changing background image when tapped -- Android

Tags: android, input, background, touch

I am trying to write a basic app that when the phone is tapped anywhere, the background image changes.
If anyone could link me to a good tutorial on how to do this or have some code snippits i could use it would be greatly appreciated.

Also is this possilble to code this in the xml or does it need to be done in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an onClick event to the layout and in the listener, change the background.

in xml

```
<LinearyLayout android:layout_height="FILL_PARENT"
    android:layout_width="FILL_PARENT" 
    android:onClick="onClick" />
```

and in your activity

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.someDrawable);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean my in my activity?

Comment: You have to create an activity and set the lineary layout as the activity's layout.